# Where does a screenshot come?

Tags: macos, display, screen-capture, gpu

I've a problem with my Mac Mini.
Sometimes, from some time, it displays some glitches, or "graphical problems", for instance the screenshot below shows some bands in a part of the screen with black or "rainbowed" flashing pixel and sometimes, when Mac wake up from sleep, all screen has a green tint. Everything solves sleeping and waking up the Mac.

[image]

I was convinced that it's a GPU problem but I went to Genius bar with these screenshot and they told me that "screenshot comes from the screen, not from the GPU, so, if glitch appears even in screenshot, problem is in the screen or the cable, not in the Mac", is it true?

Comment: "Screenshot comes from the screen, not from the GPU...". I'm missing the addition "...otherwise it would be called GPUshot" from the person behind the Genius bar.

Comment: Do you also see those glitches on the screen or do they only appear in the screenshot?

Comment: I'm with klanomoath… a screenshot of the screen is normally called a 'photograph' ;) Only if the screen looks different from the screenshot is the issue past the GPU.

Comment: Glitches appears on the screen, then I can even take a picture of them. I believed that they aren't called "GPUshot" just because "screenshot" sounds better and are easier to understand what they are. Also because, when screen links weren't digital (for instance with VGA link) how was possibile to ask to the monitor a picture of what it was displaying?

Comment: @Matte.Car I just mock the Apple Geniuses (or Mac Geniuses) ;-)

Comment: Take it back to the Genius Bar along with your display.  A PITA, I know.  Ask them to connect it to **your** display using **their** cable.  Ask them to connect it to **their** display using **your** cable.  Ask them to connect it to **their** display using **their**  cable.  If the problem persists it the across all three configurations, the GPU is the issue.

Comment: Problem is that glitches appear sometimes (like two times per week)...

Answer (score 1):

Your Genius was misinformed. When graphical artifacts or distortions show up in a screenshot, they are a product of the graphics card. It is one of the quickest tests, we did it all the time to classify graphics issues. Most geniuses know this, like I said you got someone who was either new or off their game that day.

Long story short, you're absolutely right that it's the GPU.

Comment: I'll try calling the assistance.